# diferenciar las rutas usando Spring Boot y Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

estoy trantado de resolver un problema que tengo en spring boot y las pruebas unitarias con mockito.

En mi test estoy realizando 2 llamadas http mockeadas para tratar las respuestas

```
 // -----------------------------------------------------------services
    @InjectMocks
    private SandboxAccountService accountService;

    @InjectMocks
    private SandboxBalancesService balancesService;

   @InjectMocks
   private SandboxMovementsService movementService;


    @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplateMovimientos;


 @Test
 public void test_movementsServiceImpl() throws Exception {



//LLAMADA A LISTA DE Account

List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
accountList.add(account);
accountList.add(account2);

ResponseEntity<List<Account>> list = new ResponseEntity<List<Account>>(accountList, HttpStatus.OK);


// FIRST HTTP CALL
when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString() , any(HttpMethod.class),
        any(HttpEntity.class), any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))).thenReturn(list);

//LLAMADA A LISTA DE MOVIMIENTOS

listMovent.add(movement);
listMovent.add(movementDos);

ResponseEntity<List<Movement>> listaMovi = new ResponseEntity<List<Movement>>(listMovent, HttpStatus.OK);

// Second HTTP CALL
when(restTemplateMovimientos.exchange(anyString() , any(HttpMethod.class),
        any(HttpEntity.class), any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))).thenReturn(listaMovi);






 try {
   AccountsMovementsResponse accountsMovementsResponse = 
  movementService.getMovements(accountsMovementsRequest,
        AUTORIZATHION_TOKEN, language);
  } catch (Exception e) {

   }

   }
```

Con esto cada llamda tiene su lista y al momento de hacer debug en el test funciona perfectamente, pero cuando paso al servicio.

```
  //Esta llamada http contiene la lista mockeada de cuentas correctamente
ResponseEntity<List<Account>> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(sandboxAccountURL + userId, HttpMethod.GET,entity,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Account>>() {
            });


  //Pero esta llamada no tiene movimientos, vuelve a repetir cuentas


ResponseEntity<List<Movement>> movementList = restTemplate.exchange(GenerateUrl, HttpMethod.GET,entity,
                            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Movement>>() {
                            });
```

eh intentado de todo aunque mi conocimiento con mockito es basico, si puede existir alguna manera de diferenciar las rutas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontre la respuesta, en lugar de realizar varias llamadas desde el ( when )  solo mande a realizar una y luego le pase los return que requeria segun el numero de veces que la llamada ah sido solicitada anexo la respuesta del codigo

```
 when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class),
            any(HttpEntity.class),any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))).thenReturn(list).thenReturn(listaMovi);
```